# All shortcuts behave as GOM player file

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts

My Laptop was working fine and suddenly many windows of [GOM player](http://www.gomlab.com/eng/GMP_download.html) opened at once and when I tried to close it, all icons were changed as GOM player shortcuts.

I uninstalled GOM player but still the problem isn't solved, all shortcuts behave as "open with file".

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean ALL icons? Have you tried the obvious (refreshing the desktop/window), rebooting?

If so, the GOM player may have wrote (for some reason) file associates for all your files for the GOM player in your registry. You might want to try a registry cleaning tool like [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) which is free and very good.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like GOM has changed the association for LNK files, which are your shortcuts.

Here is my registry entry for LNK files.  Copy this text into a file named **lnk.reg** on your Desktop.  Run the file and it will restore the registry settings.  You can delete the file afterwards.

**I tested this on my *Windows 7 Professional 32-bit* system.  I give no guarantee this will work on any other OS including *Windows 7 64-bit.***

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk]
@="lnkfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{00021500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
"Handler"="{ceefea1b-3e29-4ef1-b34c-fec79c4f70af}"
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  31,00,36,00,37,00,36,00,39,00,00,00
"ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30397"
"MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30318"
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew\Config]
"DontRename"=""
```

Just a note to scutinising eyes, the second line `[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk]` deletes the existing registry key, removing any corrupt data.  The entire key is recreated from scratch.